# Why vectors cannot be used as a basis for a three dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra

The following set of vectors cannot be used as a basis for a three dimensional space. Why?

> $a = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ $b =
> > \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$ $c =
> > \begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\-3\end{bmatrix}$

I was trying to find coefficients in order to know are these vectors linearly dependent. But couldn't find them - looks like they are linearly independent.

Comment: This is not a _Mathematica_ question.

Comment: This likely belongs on [math.se].  But note that `{{1, 2, 0}, {-2, 1, 3}, {4, 3, -3}} // RowReduce` yields `{{1, 0, -(6/5)}, {0, 1, 3/5}, {0, 0, 0}}`, so the vectors are in fact linearly dependent.

Comment: Maybe you are studying linear algebra. The determinant of the matrix (Det in Mathematica) might be important here.

Comment: Look at $\vec{b}+\vec{c}$.  Is it a multiple of $\vec{a}$?

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's easy to find the coefficients because 3d component is $0$, so it's clear that you need $-1b$: $0y + 3x = -3$. If we subtract b from c we're left with:

$a = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}, c - (-b)=c+b= \begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\-3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Now use either 1st or 2nd component to figure out the coefficient for $a$: $1x=2$ leaving you with 2, so $2a-1b=c$

$2\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\-3\end{bmatrix}$

Thus they are linearly dependent, so there're only 2 bases that span a 2D plane.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been to Mathematica SE,

```
a = {1, 2, 0}
b = {-2, 1, 3}
c = {4, 3, -3}}

Det[{a,b,c}]
```

> 0

That's mean the vectors are linearly dependent.

```
Solve[a == b x + c y, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/2}}

```
Solve[b == c x + a y, {x, y}]
```

{{x -> -1, y -> 2}}

```
Solve[c == a x + b y, {x, y}]
```

{{x -> 2, y -> -1}}